# Embed html string with css in a page without affecting the page's style

Tags: html, css, iframe, embed

i have some CSS for the page. I have a block of html code in form of a string, that I am simply writing on the page.

The problem is that the html string contains its own css in it and it overrides the css of the page. I need to apply that css only to the html which is in the string variable and not to the whole page.

How can I achieve this? I know I can use Iframes, but it requires "source" attribute. The html that I have is not a different page but just a simple string.

Comment: does your embedded html have css classes attached to them or they inline css?

Comment: Can you show us your code, your question is difficult to interpret without some code.

Answer (score 1):

A snippet of the HTML string would probably help, but if I understood your problem correctly, there's no way to prevent the new CSS from influencing the whole page. But if you can modify the HTML string how you want, then you only have to set the styles correctly.

Let's say your string is something like

```
<style type="text/css">
    h1 {color:red;}
    p {color:blue;}
</style>
<div>Some HTML inside</div>
```

Then you will have to change the *div*'s class and the CSS accordingly, like:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .myclass h1 {color:red;}
    .myclass p {color:blue;}
</style>
<div class="myclass">Some HTML inside</div>
```

In this way, the new CSS will only affect the new content.